# deleting first sent sms

Tags: android

Hi i want to delete the first sms from the sent item in android. i am using `uri` `content://sms/sent`. but i am getting an error. here is my code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(c);
c.moveToFirst();
String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
Log.d("TAGG", cr.delete(uri, "_id=?",new String[]{id})+" ");
```

and the exception i got

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.readingsentsms/com.example.readingsentsms.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:483)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:675)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.example.readingsentsms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
04-14 13:44:39.876: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  ... 11 more
```